# Less volatile alternative to notify-send for notifications

Tags: notification, notify-osd, libnotify

I need a mechanism similar to `notify-send` for sending notifications, but which would be more permanent - I would like the notification to only disappear when the user clicks on it, no sooner.

If user turns off the computer without clicking on the notification, I would like it to still be there on re-booting the system.

I think I am looking for something similar to Windows Actions Center.

Are there any tools to achieve my goal?

If not, what would be the alternatives? Can I, for example, manually add new unread e-mail in my e-mail client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option I see is to set up an e-mail server under Ubuntu, send notifications as e-mails to this server and then receive them in our e-mail client.